# Openlayers 4 Adding Animation Pause/Continue Functionality?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using open layers 4. I am moving and stoping marker animation as [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html) example without any problem. But I want to add pause and continue functionality to marker also. I edit some variables and endeavor on the issue with these functions. When I call `continueAnimation` function at first, the `elapsedTime` parameter become negative and give exception on `moveFeature` function. When I secondly call the `continueAnimation` function. It is working as expected. It is looking like kind of javascript implementation issue.

```
 function pauseAnimation() {
            animating = false;
            //I hold elapsed time globally
            var index = Math.round($("[id='rightfrm:tbv1:txt1']").val() * elapsedTime / 1000);
            (geoMarker.getGeometry()).setCoordinates(line_coordinates[index].lc);
            map.un('postcompose', moveFeature);
        }

 function continueAnimation() {
    animating = true;
    now = new Date().getTime();
    now = now - 10000 + elapsedTime; // --10000-- for negativeness
    geoMarker.setStyle(null);
    map.on('postcompose', moveFeature);
    map.render();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. It was a logical error. Pause and Continue working now.

```
now = new Date().getTime() - elapsedTime;
```

Anyone can use these functions for Pause/Continue functionality.

Comment: I'm also using same functionality.. Based on Animation speed, feature point should travel speed or fast.. 
`replayIndex = Math.round(speed * elapsedTime / 1000);`

Comment: So, do you suggest me to hold index variable global? @VenkataBhagyaTejaMaridu